# How to sort ArrayBuffer of Map on the basis of key value of map in scala

Tags: java, scala, playframework, scala-collections

I am sorry if the answer is very simple. I am new in Scala.
I have Array buffer of Map[String, String].
Full datatype below.

```
mutable.ArrayBuffer[mutable.Map[String, String]]()
```

I want to sort this arraybuffer on basis of key value of map.

My array buffer looks like,

```
ArrayBuffer(
    Map(youtube -> , script -> , domain -> EverydayMeArabia.com, cpc -> 0.02, is_mobile -> 0, video_width -> 0, article_id -> 423, url -> http://www.everydaymearabia.com/, mobile_device -> Desktop,Android,iPhone, number_of_article -> 1, user_rate -> null, lang -> en, campaign_id -> 45, twitter -> , name -> كيفيّة تحضير بيتزا بريمافيرا الإيطالية الأصيلة, logo -> , video -> 0, play_video -> 0, rate -> null, facebook -> , image -> ------1-size-3jpg.JPG, video_height -> 0, premium -> 0, params -> null),
    Map(youtube -> https://www.youtube.com/user/everydaymearabia, script -> , domain -> EverydayMeArabia.com, cpc -> 0.02, is_mobile -> 0, video_width -> 0, article_id -> 422, url -> http://www.everydaymearabia.com/حياة-الأسرة/نصائح-للأسرة/مقالة/كيف-تتفوقين-في-مقابلة-عمل, mobile_device -> Desktop,Android,iPhone, number_of_article -> 1, user_rate -> null, lang -> en, campaign_id -> 45, twitter -> , name -> كيف تتفوقين في مقابلة عمل؟, logo -> logoeverydaymepng.png, video -> 0, play_video -> 0, rate -> null, facebook -> , image -> -----1-size-3jpg.JPG, video_height -> 0, premium -> 0, params -> null),
    Map(youtube -> , script -> , domain -> alaan.tv, cpc -> 0.01, is_mobile -> 0, video_width -> 0, article_id -> 488, url -> http://www.alaan.tv/news/technology/130964/15-most-important-job-technology-pay, mobile_device -> Desktop,Android,iPhone, number_of_article -> 2, user_rate -> null, lang -> en, campaign_id -> 48, twitter -> , name -> 15 وظيفة تجعل من أصحابها مليونيرات في عام واحد!, logo -> , video -> 0, play_video -> 0, rate -> null, facebook -> , image -> 15jobsjpg.jpg, video_height -> 0, premium -> 0, params -> null),
    Map(youtube -> , script -> , domain -> alaan.tv, cpc -> 0.01, is_mobile -> 0, video_width -> 0, article_id -> 487, url -> http://www.alaan.tv/news/entertainment/130459/facts-reveals-serious-life-line-discovered, mobile_device -> Desktop,Android,iPhone, number_of_article -> 2, user_rate -> null, lang -> en, campaign_id -> 48, twitter -> , name -> حقائق خطيرة يكشفها خط الحياة عنكم .. اكتشفوها, logo -> , video -> 0, play_video -> 0, rate -> null, facebook -> , image -> handlinesjpg.jpg, video_height -> 0, premium -> 0, params -> null),
    Map(youtube -> null, script -> , domain -> alaan.tv, cpc -> 0.01, is_mobile -> 0, video_width -> 0, article_id -> 483, url -> http://www.alaan.tv/womens-world/entertainment/128348/countries-worlds-most-beautiful-women, mobile_device -> Desktop,Android,iPhone, number_of_article -> 2, user_rate -> null, lang -> en, campaign_id -> 48, twitter -> null, name -> أجمل فتيات العالم في هذه البلاد, logo -> , video -> 0, play_video -> 0, rate -> null, facebook -> null, image -> beautiful-womenjpg.jpg, video_height -> 0, premium -> 0, params -> null)
)
```

So want to sort this arraybuffer on basis of key "cpc"'s values. Right now it's string but in sort we can change it to double.

```
cpc -> 0.01 <<<- sort by this value of each map.
```

Which will return sorted same or new arraybuffer.

Comment: `myArrayBuffer.sortBy(m => m.get("cpc"))`

Comment: A nice thing about Scala is the rich choice of methods. Next time, you can discover the solution yourself, if you (1) use an IDE with autocompletion, (2) define your variable, e.g. `val x: ArrayBuffer[...] = ...` (3) type `x.sort` and read javadoc on the suggested methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mifeet mentioned:

```
myArrayBuffer.sortBy(m => m.get("cpc")
```

should work for you.

This page has a better demonstration how it should work. [Examples of methods available to Scala sequences](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/examples-scala-sequences-collection-methods-seq-list-array-buffer)

There would be this example:

```
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String)

val fred = Person("Fred", "Flintstone")
val wilma = Person("Wilma", "Flintstone")
val barney = Person("Barney", "Rubble")
val betty = Person("Betty", "Rubble")

val people = List(betty, wilma, barney, fred)
```

Given that data, here’s a sortBy example:

```
people.sortBy(n => (n.lastName, n.firstName))
```

Here’s what a couple of examples look like in the Scala REPL:

```
scala> people.sortBy(n => (n.lastName, n.firstName))
res1: List[Person] = List(Person(Fred,Flintstone), Person(Wilma,Flintstone), Person(Barney,Rubble), Person(Betty,Rubble))

scala> people.sortBy(n => (n.firstName, n.lastName))
res2: List[Person] = List(Person(Barney,Rubble), Person(Betty,Rubble), Person(Fred,Flintstone), Person(Wilma,Flintstone))
```

Hope it helps.